# previously working ubuntu will not boot

Tags: boot

I have a 16LTS that's been working for over a year, I just noticed it will not boot. 
I get a boot disk error. I tried to run boot-repair 3 times, noticed the boot flag was not set on the partition so tried adding that as well (no help).

When running boot-help live cd I can see the file system and files, used gparted to perform a disk check , all was good.

really lost here. any ideas will be appreciated.

boot repair logs in order.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fMMzvQWNwx/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fMMzvQWNwx/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4wQ7d24Hs9/

Comment: Suggestion: Run a SMART test to ensure your hardware is not faulty.

Comment: Thank you, I ran the SMART test but all checks out OK https://imgur.com/a/rdPTVl4

Comment: Your report shows 4040 bad sectors and five categories in Pre-Fail. In my business, I consider that entering "unreliable" territory, and put on the list for replacement soon. How soon depends upon the rate at which the number of bad sectors is increasing. Start keeping backups of data that you don't want to lose forever.